# My app keeps crashing with this java code

Tags: android

I'm just trying to create a simple calculator in android. I did everything correct. even it was showing some problem. which I just click clicked and it solved like setting final value to editText and buttons.

but when I try to run it, it just crashes and exits.

Here's the java code which I wrote for simple calculator.

- MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final EditText etNum1 = findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    private final EditText etNum2 =  findViewById(R.id.etNum2);
    private final Button btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
    private final Button btnSub = findViewById(R.id.btSub);
    private final Button btnMul = findViewById(R.id.btMul);
    private final Button btnDiv = findViewById(R.id.btDiv);
    private final TextView tvAns = findViewById(R.id.tvAns);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
                int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
                int ans = n1 + n2;
                tvAns.setText(Integer.toString(ans) );
            }
        });

        btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
                int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
                int ans = n1 - n2;
                tvAns.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }
        });

        btnMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
                int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
                int ans = n1 * n2;
                tvAns.setText( Integer.toString(ans));
            }
        });

        btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
                int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
                int ans = n1 / n2;
                tvAns.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

- ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNum1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter first number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNum2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter second number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etNum1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNum1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btSub"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btSub"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.815"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:text="SUB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNum2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btMul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="MUL"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btDiv"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btAdd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btDiv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="DIV"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btMul"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btSub" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNum2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please use a minimum reproducible example to cut out as much code as possible. This helps others in the future read and answer your problem a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to do **findViewById** after **setContentView** inside **onCreate** method

Please check below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final EditText etNum1;
private final EditText etNum2;
private final Button btnAdd;
private final Button btnSub;
private final Button btnMul;
private final Button btnDiv;
private final TextView tvAns;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etNum1 = findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    etNum2 =  findViewById(R.id.etNum2);
    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
    btnSub = findViewById(R.id.btSub);
    btnMul = findViewById(R.id.btMul);
    btnDiv = findViewById(R.id.btDiv);
    tvAns = findViewById(R.id.tvAns);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
            int ans = n1 + n2;
            tvAns.setText(Integer.toString(ans) );
        }
    });

    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
            int ans = n1 - n2;
            tvAns.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
        }
    });

    btnMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
            int ans = n1 * n2;
            tvAns.setText( Integer.toString(ans));
        }
    });

    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etNum1.getText().toString());
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etNum2.getText().toString());
            int ans = n1 / n2;
            tvAns.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
        }
    });

}
```